# Magento get attribute type (e.g. dropdown or text)

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to know how to get the type of a product attribute object. In the magento backend it is required to select between various options like "text field" or "drop down".

I'm working with a product import script and it's important to know, which type of attribute it is to set the value correctly.

Answer (score 12):

There's a simple magic method to get the value of the object:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load( $your_attribute_id );
$attribute->getFrontendInput();
```

The result is a short string, for example "text" or "select". Here's a short list of all types in Magento 1.7 (german translation):

- text: Einzeiliges Textfeld
- textarea: Mehrzeiliger Textbereich
- date: Datum
- boolean: Ja/Nein
- multiselect: Mehrfach Auswahl
- select: selected="selected: Drop-Down
- price: Preis
- media_image: Bild
- weee: Feste Produktsteuer (FPT)

If you need a list of all options from a single attribute, do this:

```
Mage::getModel( 'eav/config' )->getAttribute( 'catalog_product' , 'code_of_attribute' )
```

So you've load the attribute object. Other methods for loading an object doesn't work for me (e.g. `Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load('xy');` ).

Then use the getSource() method and the getAllOptions method to recieve an array with all options:

```
$your_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true)
```

Result looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "red"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "blue"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "green"
  }
}
```